# sql user defined function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

for a `table valued` function in sql why cant we write sql statements inside `begin` and `end` tags like-

```
create function dbo.emptable()
returns Table
as
BEGIN --it throws an error
return (select id, name, salary from employee)
END
go
```

while in `scalar valued` function we can use these tags like

```
create function dbo.countemp()
returns int
as
begin
return (select count(*) from employee)
end
go
```

is there any specific rule where we should use `BEGIN & END` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The multi-statement table-valued
>   function is slightly more complicated
>   than the other two types of functions
>   because it uses multiple statements to
>   build the table that is returned to
>   the calling statement. Unlike the
>   inline table-valued function, a table
>   variable must be explicitly declared
>   and defined. The following example
>   shows how to implement a
>   multi-statement table-valued function
>   that populates and returns a table
>   variable.

```
USE Northwind
go
CREATE FUNCTION fx_OrdersByDateRangeAndCount
( @OrderDateStart smalldatetime, 
  @OrderDateEnd smalldatetime, 
  @OrderCount smallint )
RETURNS @OrdersByDateRange TABLE
  (  CustomerID nchar(5),
     CompanyName nvarchar(40),
     OrderCount smallint,
     Ranking char(1) )
AS
BEGIN
// statements that does some processing ....

END
```

From the above, I guess `BEGIN` and `END` denotes the intent/use of multiple statements & hence it requires the table variable to be defined as shown in the code above.

from http://www.sqlteam.com/article/intro-to-user-defined-functions-updated

Answer (score 0):

In an INLINE TVF (like your first example), the `BEGIN` and `END` would try to force it to be procedural code, and therefore it would no longer be an Inline TVF. Scalar functions are only available in a procedural form (which is lousy). Therefore, Scalar functions should generally be avoided in the current versions of SQL Server.